# Module requires installation of other module

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a project that contains two modules. The module `base` is a `pom` that should be used as parent by a certain type of projects. The module `archetype` is an archetype that creates a project that uses `base` project as parent. I want to use the `maven-release-plugin` to release these projects. The problem is that `archetype` has an integration-test that requires `base` to be installed to the local repository (the `test`-goal is run on the newly created project as part of the integration test). When I prepare a release, the `maven-release-plugin` only runs the `test`-goal for each module. That means the integration-test will always fail, because `base` cannot be found, since it has not been installed. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run [`install:file-install`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) in the `pre-integration-test`-phase of the archetype, and configure it to install the required parent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar situation, where the archetype's generated project uses a Maven plugin built in the same reactor build. I use [`invoker:install`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html) to install my plugin into a local repository used just for the archetype's integration test (using the same `localRepositoryPath` for both `invoker:install` and `archetype:integration-test`); `invoker:install` actually installs all already built artifacts from the reactor, so I don't even have to specify anything. I haven't run into any ordering issue (my plugin is built before my archetypes), but would that be the case I suppose I could just add a dependency on the plugin from the archetype (in `scope=test`).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>install</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <configuration>
      <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/it-repo</localRepositoryPath>
    </configuration>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/it-repo</localRepositoryPath>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can (and probably should) define multimodule `pom` project that aggregates all these internally related modules, so they can be build within common reactor that enables them to see each other even if they're not installed to local repository. Then, you release always this `pom` project (aggregator) and all its modules (including `base` and `archetype`) along with it.

Comment: This is what I have now. The problem is that the integration-test for the archetype creates a new project that depends on `base` and cannot be made part of the reactor.

Comment: OK, I see. So it's probably not possible. I don't know a trick to dynamically attach some project to build reactor. Maybe there is some hacky way, but to be honest I can't imagine how it might work.